# How to print Status fields defined in Kubebuilder to show up when using Kubectl

Tags: kubernetes, kubectl, kubernetes-go-client, kubernetes-custom-resources, kubebuilder

How do I have to specify the comments like `+kubebuilder:printcolumn` to add columns to the output of the command `kubectl get my-crd.my-group.my-domain.com`?

I've a CRD (Custom Resource Definition) with the usual `struct`s for the specs and the status (similar to what's explained in the Kubebuilder tutorial here https://book.kubebuilder.io/cronjob-tutorial/new-api.html#adding-a-new-api).

I've a **Status** `struct` like this:

```golang
type ScheduleSetStatus struct {
    // When was the last time the Schedule Set
    // was successfully deployed.
    LastDeployTime string `json:"lastDeployTime"` // metav1.Time
    // The CronJobs that have been successfully deployed
    DeployedCronJobs []string `json:"deployedCronJobs"`
    // The CronJobs that had errors when the deployment
    // has been attempted.
    ErroredCronJobs map[string]string `json:"erroredCronJobs"` // TODO `error` JSON serialisable
}
```

Which has a few problems:

**The time field**

- I've tried that to be of type `metav1.Time` (handy formatting as they state at https://book.kubebuilder.io/cronjob-tutorial/api-design.html?highlight=metav1.Time#designing-an-api), but then this comment `// +kubebuilder:printcolumn:name="Last Deploy",type="date",JSONPath=`.status.lastDeployTime`` shows as empty in the output of `kubectl`.
- So I changed the type to be `string` (then in the controller doing `oess.Status.LastDeployTime = fmt.Sprintf("%s", metav1.Time{Time: time.Now().UTC()})`), then adding the comment `+kubebuilder:printcolumn:name="Last Deploy",type=string,JSONPath=`.status.lastDeployTime`` but still the field is shown as empty in the output of `kubectl`.

**The slice field `[]string` and the map field `map[string]string`**

- How do I configure these? Here there's no mention (when clicking on "Show Detailed Argument Help"): https://book.kubebuilder.io/reference/markers/crd.html
- In case these are not "simple types" with formatting issues when using `kubectl`, does that mean the only option I have is to make them `string` with some sort of `fmt.Sprintf(...)`?
- Any other option?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The solution was to add the code to update the resource status in
the **reconciler method** of the controller - `Reconcile(ctx context.Context, req ctrl.Request)`, like this:

```golang
    // Update the status for "last deploy time" of a ScheduleSet
    myStruct.Status.LastDeployTime = metav1.Time{Time: time.Now().UTC()} // https://book.kubebuilder.io/cronjob-tutorial/api-design.html?highlight=metav1.Time#designing-an-api
    if err := r.Status().Update(ctx, &myStruct); err != nil {
        log.Error(err, "unable to update status xyz")
        return ctrl.Result{}, err
    }
```

The special Kubebuilder annotation was all right:

```golang
//+kubebuilder:printcolumn:name="Last Deploy",type="date",JSONPath=`.status.lastDeployTime`
```

Also, Go slices and Go maps work out of the box with comments like:

```golang
...

    DeployedCronJobs []string `json:"deployedCronJobs"`

...

    ErroredCronJobs map[string]string `json:"erroredCronJobs"`
...

//+kubebuilder:printcolumn:name="Deployed CJs",type=string,JSONPath=`.status.deployedCronJobs`
//+kubebuilder:printcolumn:name="Errored CJs",type=string,JSONPath=`.status.erroredCronJobs`
```